# MySql querying hashed password by Ultimate Member Plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, hash

I have created a website with wordpress and 'Ultimate Member plugin' , user passwords in my database are hashed , i want to connect db from other server and query for login but i couldn't find what kind of hash function used for hashing password.

This is an example for `'12345678' = '$P$B7CWjJzLOWB4xNzOtWdqb3plBhWRYI.'` 
I don't have knowledge about php much, is this ready php function or should i check source codes for discover it ?

Comment: You can try with PHP functions password_hash() and password_verify()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function wp_hash_password( $password ) {
    global $wp_hasher;

    if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php' );
        // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
    }

    return $wp_hasher->HashPassword( trim( $password ) );
}
```

from: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/

Comment: Thank you to much , I was thinking that hash func is
belong to plugin.